# axi-cache command throws error/message

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I am new to the world of Ubuntu. Just few months into using it.
I was trying to use `axi-cache` command from the package `apt-xapian-index`. Instead of returning the results, it throws the following message/error:

```
No module named 'ConfigParser': only help functions are implemented, for the sake of help2man
```

While 'strace'ing the command, I found that it is trying to find a python module named `ConfigParser` in the directory `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`. I have python, python versions 2.7, 3, & 3.5 installed. Tried to install the module `ConfigParser` using `python3-pip`, but it only installs it on python3.5 as `python3` is sym-linked to `python3.5`.

How do I resolve this?

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug and there is a bug report for it  at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-xapian-index/+bug/1612948. You can attempt to port all the Python scripts in the package to Python 3 but this is probably too much work. I suggest you visit the bug report and mark it as "Yes, it affects me" to let the devs know of this bug.